# CM7: How to enable passwordless SSH login on same network?

Tags: cyanogenmod, ssh

I'm running CyanogenMod 7 and I'd like to enable passwordless SSH login to my main Linux computer on my network, but only when the phone is accessing the server over the same network. How/where should I put my .ssh/known_hosts file to enable this?

Comment: What app are you using for SSH, and does it even support this?

Comment: I'm using the SSH that is shipped with CyanogenMod, I wrote a script in Bash which will connect me to my server (ie ssh -p 1024 rfkrocktk@work-laptop), and I simply execute that. The SSH implementation is Dropbear client v0.52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html):

1. Take/[generate a public key](http://wiki.openwrt.org/oldwiki/DropbearPublicKeyAuthenticationHowto#generate.the.key.pair) of your Android device. *Don't you ever hardcode your password into scripts :)*
2. Put it into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on main computer
3. Then use `"from="` mask to limit IP/hostname to your LAN, like `from="192.168.1.*"`.

If IP range won't work, set up a fixed hostname for MAC address of your device on WLAN. Some AP firmwares, like OpenWRT, allow it.